Как откатить игру к последней версии
Я только начала изучать git. У меня возникла проблема, я 2 недели назад создавала ветку и сделала коммит. Сегодня я решила закинуть изменения на репозиторий и создала новую ветку в GitDesktop, где оставила изменения на главной ветке. Далее я нажала на Fetch origin, после того как все прогрузилось я зашла в свою игру и там появилось системное окно и я нажала reload. И игра вернулась к своему состоянию 2 недельной давности. Я спросила у chat gpt как сделать откат к последней версии, главное чтобы изменения последних двух недель не потерялись и он сказал, что сделать это будет нельзя, если я в новой ветке не сделала коммит, а посмотрев на новые ветки, я не нашла там скрипты за последние 2 недели. Подскажите пожалуйста, как вернуть игру к последней версии!

Могу сказать только одно git может вернуть почти невозвращаемое, но предпосылка к этому, что вы сделали коммит этих данных, когда либо. Если вы каким-либо образом не сохранили эти изменения и сделали сброс, то это уже не вернуть.
Тяжело понять, что именно там у вас, т.к. информации мало, вы там что-то напутали, или переключились на извлеченный коммит.
Зайдите к в консоль из своего проекта, а далее посмотрите где ветки, что они хранят и где вообще сейчас HEAD:
git log --oneline --graph --all

Эта команда выводит граф ваших коммитов с описанием, если и есть ваши данные то только там, переключайтесь между веками и коммитами может и найдете ваши данные.
git checkout <имя ветки>
git switch <имя ветки>
git checkout --detach <код коммита> //если переходите на коммит без указателей

